# Ruby print hash in grid format

Tags: ruby, hash

I'm working on coding a chess board. The structure of my board will be like this:

```
#   a b c d e f g h 
# 1 * * * * * * * *     # <= Black pieces on top
# 2 * * * * * * * *
# 3 * * * * * * * *
# 4 * * * * * * * *
# 5 * * * * * * * *
# 6 * * * * * * * *
# 7 * * * * * * * *
# 8 * * * * * * * *     # <= White pieces on bottom
```

I created an `@board` hash, which stores the value of any item in the grid (i.e. pieces or blank space).

How can I take my hash, which maps a grid location to a `"*"` currently (i.e. `@board['a8']=> '*'`, etc), and output that hash in the grid-like format?

Here's my `@board` variable:

```
def drawBoard
    @board = Hash.new   
    letter='a'
    while letter <= 'h'
            i=1
            while i<9
                @board["#{letter}#{i}"] = "*"
                i+=1
            end
        letter=letter.next
    end     
    @board  
end
```

Current output is just the hash itself. i.e.,

`{"a1"=>"*", "a2"=>"*", "a3"=>"*", "a4"=>"*", "a5"=>"*", "a6"=>"*", "a7"=>"*", "a8"=>"*", "b1"=>"*", "b2"=>"*", "b3"=>"*", "b4"=>"*", "b5"=>"*", "b6"=>"*", "b7"=>"*", "b8"=>"*", "c1"=>"*", "c2"=>"*", "c3"=>"*", "c4"=>"*", "c5"=>"*", "c6"=>"*", "c7"=>"*", "c8"=>"*", "d1"=>"*", "d2"=>"*", "d3"=>"*", "d4"=>"*", "d5"=>"*", "d6"=>"*", "d7"=>"*", "d8"=>"*", "e1"=>"*", "e2"=>"*", "e3"=>"*", "e4"=>"*", "e5"=>"*", "e6"=>"*", "e7"=>"*", "e8"=>"*", "f1"=>"*", "f2"=>"*", "f3"=>"*", "f4"=>"*", "f5"=>"*", "f6"=>"*", "f7"=>"*", "f8"=>"*", "g1"=>"*", "g2"=>"*", "g3"=>"*", "g4"=>"*", "g5"=>"*", "g6"=>"*", "g7"=>"*", "g8"=>"*", "h1"=>"*", "h2"=>"*", "h3"=>"*", "h4"=>"*", "h5"=>"*", "h6"=>"*", "h7"=>"*", "h8"=>"*"}`

**Edit:**
Thanks to David's answer, he led me toward a much more compact hash generation method as well.  The updated (and working) code:

```
def drawBoard
        @board = Hash.new   
        ('a'..'h').each do |letter|
            (1..9).each do |i|
                @board["#{letter}#{i}"] = "*"
                print @board["#{letter}#{i}"]
            end
            puts
        end
end
```

Comment: Just to clarify - rows 1,2 should be occupied by white, rows 7 and 8 should be black. Getting to your problem - why hash? 2-dimensional array (array of arrays for purists*) seems to be more natural option. Eventually hash of hashes to use natural indexes.

Comment: @BroiSatse I did think about doing a 2-D array as well.  I just chose the hash option instead for a more direct way edit specific squares (i.e. square "e3").  I could do the same thing by calling board[2][4], but I thought it would be a bit trickier

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "black pieces on top, white pieces on bottom".

Comment: Sorry, @sawa you're right.  I was referring to a standard base game of chess in my question.  Something like this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_symbols_in_Unicode

Comment: @tomtom - you could also use 2d hash, and call fields board['e'][2]. Or even create a custom class and override `[]` method, so it is stored internally as 2d array and accessed as ['e2'].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a starting point you can use.  You would need to add the row and column labels yourself, and add spaces, but this should get you going in the right direction:

```
('a'..'h').each do |letter|
  (1..8).each do |i|
     print @board["#{letter}#{i}"]
  end
  puts  # end the line
end
```

Comment: Thanks David, your suggestion also led me toward a much more compact board-generation method as well. I've put the updated full method in the question, and the output looks great.  I was implicitly searching for that "print" method instead of "puts", as that puts everything onto one line at a time.

Answer (score 3):

Provided that you can use symbols for the keys in `@board` instead of strings:

```
@board = {:"a1" => "*", ...}
```

I think the easiest would be to prepare a fixed template string, and do string format to rewrite the grids.

```
Template = <<_
 a b c d e f g h 
1 %{a1} %{b1} %{c1} %{d1} %{e1} %{f1} %{g1} %{h1}
2 %{a2} %{b2} %{c2} %{d2} %{e2} %{f2} %{g2} %{h2}
3 %{a3} %{b3} %{c3} %{d3} %{e3} %{f3} %{g3} %{h3}
4 %{a4} %{b4} %{c4} %{d4} %{e4} %{f4} %{g4} %{h4}
5 %{a5} %{b5} %{c5} %{d5} %{e5} %{f5} %{g5} %{h5}
6 %{a6} %{b6} %{c6} %{d6} %{e6} %{f6} %{g6} %{h6}
7 %{a7} %{b7} %{c7} %{d7} %{e7} %{f7} %{g7} %{h7}
8 %{a8} %{b8} %{c8} %{d8} %{e8} %{f8} %{g8} %{h8}
_

Template % @board
```

If you let `@board` be a flat array instead (which can be handled by using modulo operations), then replace the `%{..}` above with `%s`, and it will work the same way.

Comment: This is an interesting approach, I've never used fixed template strings before.  Thanks for this, I'll definitely learn more about these. I can see how this would be very useful